# Want to move subfolder files with specific name to new folder

Tags: python, data-science, glob, subdirectory, os.walk

[image]

This is the architecture of my folder I want to select all patients' data weather positive or negative and copy them into the new folder name Poisitive_Img_folder and Negative_Img_folder.

Kindly suggest me any technique. i used glob and os walk but failed to do so. In python

Comment: Can you provide more information? I feel like you should be able to match this using glob

Comment: i tried with glob but i am not getting result may be due to beginner level but here is the code

import glob 

files = glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/MURA X--Ray Finger/XR_FINGER/XR_FINGER/**/**")

for f in files:
  if(f.endswith('negative')):
    print(f)

Comment: import glob 

files = glob.glob("/content/drive/MyDrive/MURA X--Ray Finger/XR_FINGER/XR_FINGER/**/**")

for f in files:
  if(f.endswith('negative')):
    print(f)